# Changing order of data section affects result in x64 using RIP relative addressing

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm writing some x86-64 assembly, and changing the order of the data section seems to change the result.

Here is the data section:

```
        .data
pstr:   .asciz "%d\n"
a:      .long 10
b:      .long 3
c:      .long 300
dnm2:   .long 0
```

And here is the code, which is doing `a = b / a` and then printing `a`. (In a convoluted way, but this is not the issue). The current order (a, b, c) gives a result 99, while a changed order (b, a, c) gives a result 0. I am using clang to generate my executable from gcc.

```
    .text
    .globl main
 main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp

    movq    a(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    movq    b(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, %rax
    movq    %rax, a(%rip)
    movq    %rbx, dnm2(%rip)
    movq    a(%rip), %rax
    movq    dnm2(%rip), %rbx
    xorq    %rdx, %rdx
    idiv    %rbx
    movq    %rax, a(%rip)

    movq    a(%rip), %rsi
    leaq    pstr(%rip), %rdi
    call    printf@PLT

    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Comment: `.long` is not 64 bit as you might expect, it's 32 bit. See the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Long.html). You want `.quad`. Actually, since you only use `%d` it seems like you want 32 bit operations, so the data is fine but you are using 64 bit operands in the instructions. Fix either one to match the other.

Comment: In addition, there are many redundant code, it seems strange if it's hand-written.

Comment: @Jester thank you, that solves the problem. .long seemed to work for most of the stuff I did before, so I just kept on using it for 64bit operations as well.

Comment: @liliscent It's not handwritten, I am trying to generate it.

Comment: x86 is little-endian, so if the next 4 bytes happen to be zero, an 8-byte load will get the same value as a 4-byte load.  (But an 8-byte store will step on those zeros.)